# Async Class Based Views in Django

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django and I have been working on a Stripe based application and I found out that my class based views are quiet slow and I need to make them run as fast as possible. I discovered that in Django there is **Asynchronous Support** available but I am unable to figure how can I use it in class based views everywhere I find there are functional based example just.

Django documentation that I was looking into was: [Django Asynchronous Support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/async/)

I want to make my Stripe call faster. Any help will be appreciated I am new and learning Django.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need to improve performance, [start with a profiler](https://medium.com/kami-people/profiling-in-django-9f4d403a394f). The slow part might not be what you expect.

I suspect, in particular, that calling the Stripe API as part of a routine JSON conversion could be slow. You may want to cache a copy of the Stripe API data in a `Subscription` model, so you don't have to hit an external API on every request. However ... again ... make sure you profile first.

Comment: I know the reason is because of stripe. I don't want to put load on my model as this is just for displaying purpose only. There's no need to store it that's why I am not storing it in my model.

Comment: OK. I think that using async Django is only going to give you a tiny performance boost if any, compared to the Stripe API call time.

Comment: Can you guide me how can I use async for stripe calls? I am a little stuck